# How do i retrieve Data from Firesbase to textField in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
@IBOutlet weak var fullName: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fullName.delegate = self

    var refHandle = self.ref.child("profile").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

  let userDict = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
```

// Here i am geting the Full Name value but i cant set textfield equal to it

```
    })
```

Comment: Add more details to the question and also add what you had tried.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that is failing. Also include information on how it fails. What is the error message?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the vlaue of fullName from firebase in my actual fullname textfield, i tried snapshot.value [forKey "fullname"]